# Complex 0/1 Backpack with multiple compartments

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Say I have 3 compartments in my backpack: red, green, blue and 3 sets of items: red items, green items and blue items which all have a weight and benefit. I also have a requirement around the total number of total items that MUST be placed in each compartment of the backpack. Red Compartment MUST have 2 red items, Green Compartment MUST have 3 green items and the blue compartment MUST have 3 blue items. My backpack can hold some kind of max weight. I need to optimize for the max value given some weight.

To solve this problem I attempted to use the branch and bound technique used for solving the 0/1 backback. This technique computes quickly but picks items that leave too much left over space and doesn't return the optimal items.

What techniques can be used to solve this in a reasonable amount of time (aka not brute forcing every possible combination)? I am unfamiliar with dynamic programming but is this something better suited to that or is there a different technique I can use?

Comment: How many red items do you have to choose from?

Comment: number of red, green, blue items can be anywhere from 1...10,000 (basically enough so that brute force will take forever)

Comment: You can use dynamic programming to find the list of best value for each weight, for each of the colors. For example, if the backpack's total max weight is 100, then dynamic programming can be used to find the best value for two red items with a combined weight between 1 and 100. Likewise for blue and green. Once you have those lists, then you can create a list that combines two colors, and then combine the two-color list with the third color. In other words, yes, you need to become familiar with dynamic programming.

Comment: It's an integer linear program. Use GLPK or a similar solver.

Comment: GLPK looks amazing, having trouble finding some resources on learning the syntax anyone know a place I find a good tutorial or rundown?

Comment: The download for GLPK contains documentation. Also see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Literature

Comment: There is an *enormous* amount of stuff out there on modelling and solving problems with mixed-integer solvers like GLPK, lpsolve, etc. What suits you best depends highly on what your background is like. Are you a maths-oriented theoretical person, or prefer a more directly practical engineering approach? Are you used to high-level modelling tools and environments like Matlab, or happier with lower-level languages like Python, C#, C++, VB etc. I personally prefer the lpsolve IDE for learning as I found GLPK harder to use, but then I use bigger solvers like CPLEX, Xpress or Gurobi for real work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting problem! Yes, this problem can be solved with dynamic programming.

To understand how to solve, you first need to understand how knapsack is solved using dynamic programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem.

You can see that recursive function solving Knapsack has only one argument, that is remaining weight. To modify your problem you would need to "drag" along three more argument, which are storing how close to fulfilling each of compartment's conditions we are. Recursive function would therefore have 4 arguments.

Hope this helps.